# SQL Server ConnectionString: . for Data Source

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string

So I'm working with a SQL Server 2008 connection string:

```
Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False
```

What is the `.` Data Source?  How can I connect to the `.` Data source using SSMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` = `(local)` = whatever the name of the machine is from which the connection is being initiated. It is *similar* to using `localhost`, except that `localhost` forces a TCP connection to be established, whereas `.` or `(local)` can use the shared memory connection provider.

You can similarly put `.` or `(local)` as the server name in the SSMS connection dialog, to connect to the local default instance.

Answer (score 1):

Data Source is the servername with a default instance

What you put there depends on whether this server is on the box as the SSMS you're using, or remote.

- If remote, use the actual server name
- If local, you can use `(local)` or `localhost`